# How to send an email with OTP when customer register in prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I am a beginner in prestashop.I want to send an email with otp to the mail id given by customer when user click on the "register" button.the otp should expires in 5s.Help me with useful advice

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.